# query for past orders using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a query for past orders from a oracle database and i want to search by Company name.
I am not sure where to start with accessing the database

Here is the basic command line prompt i created but i not sure

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PastOrders {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        system.out.prinln("Welcome to Company XYZ Order Query");
        system.out.println();

        Sting companyName;
        System.out.print("Enter Company Name to pull up previous orders: ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to download and the Java Data Base Connector (JDBC) for you Database. For oracle you can find it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Then you have to set up a connection, write and execute a query, like this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html):

```
 import java.sql.*;

public class UpdateCar {

public static void UpdateCarNum(int carNo, int empNo)
    throws SQLException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;   

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                  "jdbc:default:connection");

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE EMPLOYEES " +
                    "SET CAR_NUMBER = ? " +
                    "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = ?");

        pstmt.setInt(1, carNo);
        pstmt.setInt(2, empNo);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    finally {
        if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
    }
}
}
```

The only thing you have to change in this sample code is the PreparedStatement(psmt - query) and the Connection(con).

Comment: I am new to importing database and running a SQL query with JAVA, so how would i incorporate it with my original program,  Also would the SQL be something like SELECT order_numder, date, name, FROM (database-name) WHERE name = string variable

Comment: Just copy the sample code above from line "Connection con = null" and paste it on your main methon. Of course you also need to add the jar jdbc to your project's build path.

Comment: Sorry so everything up to "Connection con= null" or everything from that done,  and where would i add it to mine,   THANKS for your help